# Which archive format is streamable and can encrypt the filenames too?

Tags: encryption, streaming, zip, filenames, rar

For example Zip is streamable or pipeable (at least the Linux version), but can not encrypt the filenames, only the data. 7zip and Rar are non streamable, eg it is impossible to pipe the compressed data to another program in the command line, as the archiver makes random seeks in the file, while it is written to the disk. However they can encrypt the filenames, which is a handy feature. I would like to use an archiver, which can do both at the same time: pipeable and encrypts the filenames too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Tar, then encrypt (with e.g. GPG or ccrypt), then gzip (or zip). What started out as filenames are treated as data once your files are gathered into a tarball, so they'll be encrypted along with the file contents.